# BoundingBox around plot in mapview

Tags: raster, r, sf, mapview

I wanted to plot some raster-data with mapview. I always get this greyish bounding box around my data though. Anybody an idea of what this might be?
I just call `mapview(<raster>)`

[image]

Comment: You need to set `na.color = "transparent"` so your NA values are not shown

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot!!